# I have two tensorflow program, How to keep same initial values for weights and bias?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tensorflow programs in python with small difference but the same number of weights and biases in total for both the programs.

For comparison purposes, I want to start both the programs with a same initial state.

Program 1

```
import tensorflow as tf

def getVariable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

W = getVariable([10, 10])
b = getVariable([10,10])
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
r = W * b
print(sess.run(r))
```

Program 2

```
import tensorflow as tf

def getVariable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

W1 = getVariable([10, 10])
b1 = getVariable([10,10])
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
r1 = W1 * b1
print(sess.run(r1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow has 2 different PRNG and each of them requires a seed that's used to generate random values.

The first PRNG is the graph's one, the second is the operation level one.

If you don't explicitly set these seeds, tensorflow will use a random value and thus you'll always generate different values.

To set the graph seed you have to use [`tf.sed_random_seed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed):

```
tf.set_random_seed(1)
```

To set the operation level you have to pass a seed to each operation that generates random values, in your case:

```
tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1, seed=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_random_seed` like this:

```
tf.set_random_seed(42)

def getVariable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

W = getVariable([10, 10])
#...
```

And yet if you do this you will still get different values between executions. To get the same numbers in both your programs you still need to reset the graph to default using `tf.reset_default_graph()` 
at the beginning of your code.